# replace JSON object value single quote with double quote

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

My JSON response values have single quote but I want double quote. I have already tried `JSON.stringfy()` and `JSON.parse()`, they both are not working.

**Response:**

```
[
  {
    title: 'Car',
    price: 2323,
  }
]
```

**Expected Response:**

```
[
  {
    title: "Car",
    price: 2323,

  }
]
```

Basically, I want to use that response in shopify graphql query.

```
mutation {

    productCreate(input: {
      id:"gid://shopify/Product/4725894742116"
      title: "This is a car",
        variants:[{
        title:"car",
        price: 12
        }]
    }) {
      product {
        id
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: why do you need double quotes?

Comment: @Richard I want to use in graphql query, The query only accepts value with double quotes .

Comment: that’s not valid json and should be fixed upstream if possible. json requires double quotes around the keys and the string values. where are you getting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string
and The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string.

```
let obj =[
  {
    title: 'Car',
    price: 2323,
  }
];

let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));



console.log(result);
```

the result is

```
[
  {
    title: "Car",
    price: 2323,

  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see, any problem using `JSON.stringify` you can either get the string directly and use it inside a query or if you need a javascript object, you can just parse it.

[JSON.Stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

[Passing arguments in GraphQl](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments/)

```js
const unwantedResponse = [{
  title: 'Car',
  price: 2323,
}]

const wantedResponse = JSON.stringify(unwantedResponse);
const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(wantedResponse)

console.log(wantedResponse);
console.log(parsedResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could apply: [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (which converts a JS object to a JSON string), then [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) (which parses a JSON string back to a JS object), *e.g.*

```js
let x = [{
  title: 'Car',
  price: 2323,
}];
x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
console.log(x);
```